# Installing molding on sloping ceiling

Tags: molding

I'm trying to install molding but stuck on the angle where the ceiling is sloping. See pic to demonstrate the angles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9AfZ.jpg sorry not the greatest quality.

[image]

The two walls (striped wall paper) forms a closet. I'm trying to figure out what angle is needed to cut both molding to join seamlessly at corner in the center of the pic. Normally it's just a 45 degree cut for a 90 degree wall but the sloping ceiling complicates things a lot.

Hope it's clear. Can provided more info if not.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no angle for making a symmetrical joint of the two pieces  Cutting the left trim to meet the corner requires a 55 degree angle where the right piece is approx. 90 degrees.  The vertical ends are not the same length.  Any profile in the trim will only enhance the mismatched appearance.

There are several approaches you can use to make the junction appear presentable. if the trim profile is a simple rectangle you can simply chamfer the bottom edge of the left trim to meet the bottom of the trim on the right.  Another approach would be to create a vertical corner trim to receive both trim pieces.  You would rabbet a corner of some square trim stock so that the profile  would be "L" shaped to fit the corner with enough depth to receive the full depth of the moldings.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it needs a "compound" bevel, where the saw positioned at 45-degrees in the first axis, then at 27.5- degrees in the second axis.